# Programmatically changing the global site name?

Tags: tokens, theming, configuration, 7, meta-tags

I'm making a multi-site setup using the same install and the same database, basing it off domains. I'm trying to programmatically alter the site_name variable so that it displays a different site name based on the domain being used.

I am using 3 different methods to achieve this at the same time, however even that is not bullet-proof. Certain instances (i.e. some administration pages, user login, or user profile edit) still display the default site name in the page title (or elsewhere).

I am doing the following:

- `$conf['site_name'] = $my_title;` in settings.php
- `$vars['site_name'] = $my_title;` in my theme's hook_preprocess_page
- using `hook_tokens_alter` in a custom module to change the `[site:name]` token to `$my_title`

Despite all these measures, it seems I did not enforce the site name change in a bulletproof way. Is there a better method I have missed?

Worth mentioning: I am using the Metatag module, which seems to alter page titles on a fundamental level. I am not sure if this is related to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From PHP code, it's just:

```
variable_set('site_name', 'My Site Name');
```

If it doesn't work, clear you caches, restart your memcached if you're using it or check if you didn't export it into Features or hardcoded into your settings file.

One-time go is via drush:

```
drush -y vset site_name "My Site Name"
```

To check if the value was changed:

```
drush vget site_name
```

Answer (score 3):

What is the value for the `site_name` variable in the `variables` table? (e.g. what's the output of `variable_get('site_name')`?)

If it's overridden from the value that you set in your settings file, reset it like so:

`variable_set('site_name', $my_title)`