# how can I change the site name

Tags: 6, path-aliases

For some reason, I'm not able to change the name of this site.  I try to change the name to 'Test Name', as shown in this screenprint:

[image: Screenshot of site information page]

But after I save the page, the name is repopulated with the previous title.

It is an old drupal site with many years of modules and various admins working on it, so anything's possible. It does have [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) installed, but I can't see any place where that is overriding the site title.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you checked the templates to see if someone hardcoded it in?

Answer (score 2):

Look in settings.php; I expect someone set $conf['site_name'] = 'Test name'.  Anything hard-coded there cannot be overridden.

Comment: Good guess, but we're not setting 'site_name' there..

Comment: Do you have drush installed?  If so, run:
drush vset site_name "my new site name"

Then run:
drush vget site_name

It should return "my new site name".  If it doesn't, then you've got code somewhere overriding the global $conf['site_name'] value.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the title is hard coded somewhere in your template or module files.  I recommend running the grep command in the command line to find which file(s) have the title hard coded.

```
grep -r "My Title" sites/default
```

Comment: Also a good guess.  The title _has_ been hardcoded for a few content types, but none of them are what I'm looking for..

Answer (score 0):

According to [drupal documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1525472) You can set it  in `settings.php`  with  `$conf['site_name'] = 'Test name'.`

Also in drupal ,  `site name`  registered with `variables` so you can get  or set it with variable API

for set it  use

```
  variable_set('site_name', 'My New site name');
```

[This link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/129784/programmatically-changing-the-global-site-name)  can help you if you could'nt set it in your `settings.php`.

Comment: This is insufficiently persistent. Settings.php, as reference by Aaron, will update this variable's value on bootstrap.

Comment: @Screenack in settings.php make it run every time but if he just want just one time set it , he can set it with this method.

Comment: If I understand the original post, s/he's unclear why the title isn't updating based on changing the site settings page. Setting the variable will only be temporary, or as albertski suggests, mooted by logic or hard-wired code in template.php or template files.

Comment: @Screenack I don't have discuss in this topic, it can cause several reason,I just suggest one solution to changing `site_name` ( before Pierre update the question, it was how change the site name of the site ) !!!!

Comment: I don't mean to pick on you — the discussion might help the next person who comes along.

Comment: To whom it may concern: the very first version of the question title was "Why can't I change site title?" ... and NOT "How change the site name of the site". Look at the revision history for the proof of that ... Moreover, in "my" edit of the question, I did NOT (repeat NOT) change the title ... Look at the revision details to find out "who" changed the title afterwards, from "**Why** can't I change ..." to "**How** can I change ...". Clear enough? I believe a rollback to version 2 is appropriate here (to not change to intend of the OPer) ...